# How to access a kernel driver functions

Tags: interface, linux-device-driver, uart, ftdi, rs485

I want to use the [FTDI driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c) to connect to the FT232R with [RS485 level shifter](https://ftdichip.com/products/usb-rs485-we-1800-bt/). I am aware that the author [recommends](http://ftdi-usb-sio.sourceforge.net/) the POSIX or libusb patterns to implement the desired functions.

However I'm curious if there is a method to use the [functions from the driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c) itself.

for example if I want to use the function

```c
    static int  ftdi_open(struct tty_struct *tty, struct usb_serial_port *port);
```

How can I go about it? Is there a place where some documentation is available?

Comment: *"However I'm curious if there is a method to use the functions from the driver itself."* -- From userspace?  What values would you pass to the driver for the required parameters?  The simple answer is no.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible to adapt driver to use RS485 IOCTLs, so user space program can control this mode.